# Dot net core web API url tries to make use of the internet through ajax call

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Working on a dot net web API hosted on my local IIS and each time i try to call the API from a mobile application i'm developing, i get Internal server error(500). After several hours of debugging, i copied that is being sent to the API from ripple emulator i'm using on chrome and tried to do a get action manually. What i noticed though is after specifying localhost url and every necessary thing, the browser tries to search for it though google rather than use address specified .

```
> public class Program
>     {
>         public static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
>         }
> 
>         public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
>             WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

       .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

program file above and start up file below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });



            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowCors", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                                                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                                   .AllowCredentials()
                                                                    .AllowAnyHeader()));
            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
            });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }




public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowCors");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            //app.UseMiddleware<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Comment: are u using a proxy ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178120.aspx or check your hosts file for an entry localhost